# Do I need passport.js if I use Auth0 as my Auth service for my React app?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, auth0

I understand that passport.js is a way to implement app server side authentication, but if I am using Auth0 as the authentication service for my React app, do I still need passport.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate users in a React app with `auth0-react` without other libraries such as passport.js. See [Auth0 React SDK Quickstarts](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login).